# Why not use GCC constructor/destructor?

Tags: c, gcc

[libabc](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/kay/libabc.git/tree/README) recommends not using GCC constructors/desctructors, but the explanation is rather short:

> Do not use gcc constructors, or destructors, you can only loose if
>   you do. Do not use _fini() or _ini(), don't even use your own
>   explicit library initializer/destructor functions. It just won't
>   work if your library is pulled in indirectly from another library
>   or even a shared module (i.e. dlopen())

Can someone explain what the problems are and what could break, especially with GCC on different platforms?

Comment: Well, it is in the section about completely avoiding global state. If you follow that, what would you need constructor or destructor functions for?

Answer (score 2):

When writing a library, the best approach is to have no dependencies on other libraries, no dependencies on state data at all (certainly no use of global variables for state and synchronization within the library), clean and simple interfaces, and all of the other basic principles of good software engineering.

What the README for libabc is providing is a fairly good list of all the ways that the writers have found to make a library difficult to use or to introduce various kinds of subtle defects.

What the authors are saying is that it is difficult to predict how your library will be used and the environment in which it will be running therefore you should be paranoid about how you implement functionality and what kinds of services from the operating system and any other libraries you might use.

For instance see [Shared Library Constructor is not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646211/shared-library-constructor-is-not-executed).

Or [When (and how) are C++ global static constructors called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271248/c-when-and-how-are-c-global-static-constructors-called).

Or [GCC constructor NOT execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085992/gcc-constructor-not-execute).

Comment: How is a library not depending on another library the "best approach"? An awful lot of libraries depend on other libraries. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @rubenvb, there is a difference between the best approach and the most reasonable approach.  The problem with depending on libraries is that it is one more thing to go wrong.  On the other hand, libraries provide a way to get work done quicker and easier.  The question is whether the library dependency is a necessity or not.  This particular context is providing a library to be used by others and what the libabc comments are saying is it is better to not depend on other libraries.  If dependencies change, the change may ripple into your library creating mysterious failures.